# How to add Textfield under Appbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a TextField under the top App bar in my paint app but I can't figure out how. I tried looking for solutoins online but didn't find any...

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Center(child: new Text("Draw 1102 - Beta Version", textAlign: TextAlign.center))),
      body: 
      Column(children: <Widget>[ TextField() ],),  // Does not work
      Container( 
        child: GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details)
          {
            setState(()
            {
              RenderBox _object = context.findRenderObject();
              //More code...
            });
          },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [PreferredSize Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html) as the AppBars `bottom` Property.
The PreferredSize Widget has a child as well, where you can put your TextField.

You just need to find the right `height` for the PreferredSize manually.

Answer (score 1):

AppBar I got:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwYEM.jpg

```
    appBar: AppBar(
      toolbarHeight: 110, // Set this height
      flexibleSpace: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Row(children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(width: 15),
            Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text("Demo",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23, color: Colors.white))
          ]),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Container(
              height: 40,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
              child: TextField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                controller: search,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                    hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black38),
                    hintText: "Search"),
              )),
        ]),
      ),
    )
```